# Error on "rails new" command (using rbenv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rbenv

I have rbenv installed, ruby, and rails installed, but the command to create the new rails project is causing an exception around sqlite.

```
rails new first_app
.
.
.
Using sass (3.2.3) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/alundgren/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/alundgren/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local


Gem files will remain installed in /home/alundgren/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/alundgren/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried installing the `sqlite` gem and rehashing `rbenv`, but same error. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this, what the exact gem name is, etc?

Comment: did you try the suggestion in the log?  Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal' or 'yum install sqlite-devel'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I installed a the sqlite package on ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks @NeilDoshi your answer solved my problem. Funny thing is I thought I had already installed the dev libs for sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing the required header files to compile the mysql adapter.  The error suggests "Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal' or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the location where your sqlite3 shared library is located)".  I would do that first, as this will ensure that you have the correct header files on your machine.  Once you have them, you may have to specify the location of the files to the compiler, the "--with-sqlite3-include" directive will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have *sqlite* installed on your box. The gem will not installed without the underlying being present.

Please do:

- macosx: `brew install sqlite`
- enterprise linux: `sudo yum install libsqlite3-dev`
- ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`